# How do I notifyDataSetChanged in ArrayAdapter inside a callback on a different thread? - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am making a network call, then once the network call is done retrieving the information, I would like to call notifyDataSetChanged.  This works if it's all on the same thread, but how would I go about updating the list if the update is happening in another thread?

**

It will throw this error:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: `BroadCast Receiver` use

Comment: whats the problem with calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the UI thread?

Comment: if I have your code, I can help better. you have 2 ways. first is used broadcastReceiver, second is used interface in network methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a handler.
Declare your adapter like an atribute of the class (outside any method).
And use this code in your activity:

```
public Handler updateAdapter = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        //Update code
    }
});
```

And this one in your thread (to call the handler):

```
updateCode.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: beautiful, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask to perform your networking operation on a separate thread. You start the AsyncTask from your UI thread and the task itself will run on a separate thread. When the AsyncTask is done, AsyncTask's onPostExecute method will run on the UI thread again from which you can call the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

[Here's some useful info on AsyncTask in the Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)